# I am trying to run a python script from a click of a button in my HTML code using Ajax

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax

My JS code -

```
function callPythonScript() {
                alert("called");
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://localhost:5000/app.py",
                    type: "POST",
                    // data: {
                    //     "var1": 'value1',
                    //     "var2": "value2"
                    // },
                    success: function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr) {
                        console.log(xhr);
                    }
                });
            }
```

button code -

```
<button class="button button1" onclick="callPythonScript()" value = "Display">Click Here to open a request</button>
```

Python Code -

```
import cgi
import requests
import json
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
var1 = form.getvalue('var1')
var2 = form.getvalue('var2')

def api_call():
    url = "https://instance.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident"

    payload = json.dumps({
    "short_description": "onclickbutton test api"
    })
    headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic auth',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

    return (response.text)

api_call()
```

Error which i get in console -
[image]

I don't understand why i get cors policy error when both my server and page is on same host.

I tried to add the file path locally instead on hosting i get the same cors policy error.
Please suggest a different approach to run a python script from HTML and pass values as well.
TIA

Comment: Your Python code is not sending the proper CORS headers to allow for the cross-domain traffic you're attempting to send. Without a [mre] of the Python code you *believe* should work, it's not really possible to help you. See [ask]

Comment: @esqew , Edited my question added my python code which i am triggering on the click of the button.

Comment: Also `http://localhost:5000/app.py` you're expecting an HTTP call to a script to _run_ the script and not serve it? You need to call the code from whatever server is listening at port 5000... (Putting the name of your python file in the URL would mostly not run your python code, unless you have some server configured to do that which is weird since mostly people would prefer calling specific functions and using their return value)

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat, I tried to invoke my script by just giving the local path.
 `alert("called"); $.ajax({ url: "app.py", type: "POST",`
Still i am getting cors policy error

Comment: What server is running on port 5000 that you expect to execute this code? How is it configured to do so?

Comment: @esqew 
i just started a very basic python http server using this command `python -m http.server --cgi `

I Read this documentation , i didnt configure the server any further if that is possible using this command [https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was initiating the server using "python -m httpserver"

This server is a simple server and wont be able to run your code when called, we need to use Flask or Django , i used Flask because i needed a very simple server with very less configurations, Using Flask i was able to bypass CORS policy error by adding `app = Flask(__name__) CORS(app)`